# Execute list of async tasks

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a list of async functions I want to execute in order. When I run the following code I get the output:

```
Task 1 before
Task 2 before
Finished tasks
```

Why are my async functions not being awaited correctly?

```
    [Test]
    public async Task AsyncTaskList()
    {
        var data = "I'm data";
        var tasks = new List<Func<object, Task>>() {Task1, Task2};

        tasks.ForEach(async task =>
        {
            await task(data);
        });

        Debug.WriteLine("Finished tasks");
    }

    private static async Task Task1(object data)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Task 1 before");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Debug.WriteLine("Task 1 after");
    }

    private static async Task Task2(object data)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Task 2 before");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Debug.WriteLine("Task 2 after");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `await` inside your `ForEach` delegate actually completes *after* the method exits. Change it to an actual `foreach` loop and awaiting will work as expected.

`ForEach` has no specific handling for `Func<Task>` (few delegate-accepting methods in the Base Class Library do, and you should note that they will almost invariably return a `Task` themselves). `ForEach` will only run the *synchronous* portion of your lambda - and that is the portion *preceding* the first `await` of a `Task` which does not complete synchronously (which is `Task.Delay` in your case). This is why you're seeing the "before" messages popping up at the expected time. As soon as your delegate hits `await Task.Delay`, the the rest of your lambda is *scheduled* to run sometime in the future and `ForEach` moves on to the next item in the list. The scheduled task continuations will then run unobserved and complete later.

Comment: Actually it works, sorry. I must've been looking at the wrong output. Thanks

Comment: @SimonTrewhella, no problem. I've added a more detailed explanation too.